# MTM - Error saving the test run :There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

When I start to run the automated test case in Test Agent through Test Manager, Run Log shows below error. Test Agent has the enough memory space on the disk. What could be the issue? Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually test controller was runs out of space because of the files being stored in localappdata%\VSEQT\QTController\TestRunStorage which never get deleted. So to resolve the issue, we have to remove the all files from TestRunStorage folder or turn off job spooling in QTController.exe.config file. Please refer following reference links for more details.

Reference Links:

http://www.anujchaudhary.com/2011/06/tfs-2010-test-controller-disk-runs-out.html

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shivash/2011/01/20/using-visual-studio-test-controller-with-mtm-and-disk-out-of-space-issues/